# Ruby on Rails 3 - Color select plugin

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, colors, rubygems

I'm looking for a ruby gem or jquery plugin to pick simple colors: green, red, blue, yellow, etc. **NOT** an RGB color code selector.

Does anyone know of a good plugin/gem?

Comment: Are you trying to build a form element or JS control for choosing from a restricted set of named colors with predefined hex/RGB values? Is there some reason you can't just output a list of radio buttons for each of the colors you want?

Comment: it's a form element. Radio buttons are an option; a less sleek option however.

Comment: Well, can you describe, then, what you want the actual solution to look and function like? I would start with a form element, and use CSS to make the radio buttons look like buttons of the appropriate color.

Comment: There are some colorpickers with predefined color option. http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-color-pickers-plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution.

Build a set of radio buttons into your form for the color options.

Use Bootstrap button groups for checkboxes and radio buttons for basic style and behavior:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-examples

Alternately, use a style and behavior plugin like this:
http://ghinda.net/css-toggle-switch/#radio

Write your own CSS classes based on the color options to change the color of the button/toggle to match that of the chosen color.

**I think this is what you really want:**

Alternately, use this plugin and configuration:
http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/#toc16